# Use of HTTP error codes in web app

Tags: web-applications, http-headers

Is there any reason why a web site/app should use proper HTTP error codes when responding to POST requests?

Imagine I have a signup form. If a user attempts to register a new account with an email address or a user name that already exists, the web app will respond with some kind of error message and prevent the user from moving forward. The question **is if there is any value in setting an appropriate status code on the response?** After all, the user will not be able to tell the difference unless she opens the browser's debugging tools.

Comment: error codes is not meant to reflect the web-application response, its meant to be used by the application server. typically, application logic should always return 200. and the response content should contain any  application-logic related stuff.

Comment: Basically HTTP status codes are for browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a value.

In your example, if a non-human agent attempts to login, it could have difficulty distinguishing a successful or failed login ... if you don't set appropriate error codes.